# Share a file from shared with me folder in Microsoft one drive using graph api

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, sharepoint-online

Is it possible to share the file from my **Shared with me** folder to other user using **Microsoft Graph API**.

Example:

- User_1 created file_1 and shared it with User_2.
- User_2 wants to share file_1 with User_3.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you are new user, I recommend you read ["How to Ask a Good Question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Asking question properly will help you get better answers and help others be able to understand your question if they have a similar problem.

Comment: My production release is pending because of this. Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot share a file someone has shared with you. Only the owner of the file can dictate how and with whom a file is shared. The alternative (allowing re-sharing of a file) would open a huge security hole as the actual owner would have no idea who has access to their data.

Comment: I have observed  that we can share a file from shared with me folder from one drive ui on clicking Share button then why it's not possible with graph api's.